# Android play video in raw folder (launching gallery from intent)

Tags: android, video, android-intent, gallery

So I know there are a lot of questions on this, but all seem to have the same answer and it's not what I'm looking for.

I have a video in the `raw` folder in my project, and I can get it to play in my app with `VideoView`. However, I would like to take advantage of the gallery video player that all phones come with so the user can pause or scroll through the video.

When I try to open my video with an `ACTION_VIEW` intent, it appears that there are no apps that can handle the intent. I have the same video in a folder in my phone, and the gallery player can play it fine. I also downloaded VLC but still no apps show up in the list. Is it just not possible, or am I missing something?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ActivityMain.PACKAGE_NAME + "/" + R.raw.test));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ActivityMain.PACKAGE_NAME + "/" + R.raw.test), "video/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few apps support the `android.resource` scheme. Copy the video to a file and play that, or embed your own video player.

Comment: But I can play it with the gallery, that comes with my phone. Does it not support it either? What is the point of having a robust video player that comes with every phone but not being able to use it?

Comment: So you are saying that copying the video from raw to a location on the phone, and the opening it through the gallery would work?

Comment: @aspirino67: "What is the point of having a robust video player that comes with every phone but not being able to use it?" -- there are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. These will ship with hundreds of different video player apps pre-installed. Not all are "robust". Moreover, playing videos embedded in other apps as raw resources is not a particularly common case.

Comment: @aspirino67: "So you are saying that copying the video from raw to a location on the phone, and the opening it through the gallery would work?" -- assuming it's a valid video file, sure. There's no difference then between the video you copied out there and a video that, say, you downloaded from a Web site.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help you,use `video/mp4`...

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw. test);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It still won't work, there are no apps that can handle the intent.

Comment: Not all devices may have activities set up to support ACTION_VIEW on video/mp4 files that are streamed.